# Replace variable string on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to create string inside "code" variable that adds up selected image value into code variable. Final code should look for example like this: "test1/A=1a/B=1b" or "test2/A=1b/B=1a" and so on. If user edits icon "A" it should replace this value inside code and not add up like in snippet.

See snippet below.

```js
let code;

$(".selectIco").click(function(){
  $(".iconSelect").html("");
  $(this).clone().appendTo(".iconSelect");
})

let thisIcon;
$(".clone").on("click", function() {
  thisIcon = $(this);
  $(".iconSelect").html("");
    $(".icons").slideDown("1000");

function imagePicker() {
  $(".selectIco").on("click", function() {
    $(".iconSelect").html("");
    $(this).clone().appendTo(".iconSelect");
    $(thisIcon).html("");
    $(".iconSelect img").clone().appendTo(thisIcon);
  })
}
imagePicker();
    })

$(".test1").click(function(){
  code = "test1";
  console.log(code);
})
$(".test2").click(function(){
  code = "test2";
  console.log(code);
})

//code
  $('.cloner1').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    if ($(this).children("img").length > 0 ) {
      iconA = $(this).children(".selectIco").attr("value");
      code += "A=" + iconA;

      console.log("export of code = " + code);

    }
  });
    $('.cloner2').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    if ($(this).children("img").length > 0 ) {
      iconA = $(this).children(".selectIco").attr("value");
      code += "B=" + iconA;

      console.log("export of code = " + code);

    }
  });
```

```css
.iconSelect {
  height 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.clone {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height:120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.icons {
  display: none;
}
.test1, .test2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>first</h1>
<div class="test1">clickme</div>
or
<div class="test2">clickme</div>
<br/>

<h1>second</h1>
<div class="clone cloner1">A</div>
<div class="clone cloner2">B</div>

<div class="iconSelect"></div>
<div class="icons">
  <img  class="selectIco" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/100px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" value="/1a">
  <img class="selectIco" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Gmail_Icon.svg/100px-Gmail_Icon.svg.png" value="/1b">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the last two times you're modifying `code` from `+=` to `=` and it works fine:

```js
let code;

$(".selectIco").click(function() {
  $(".iconSelect").html("");
  $(this).clone().appendTo(".iconSelect");
})

let thisIcon;
$(".clone").on("click", function() {
  thisIcon = $(this);
  $(".iconSelect").html("");
  $(".icons").slideDown("1000");

  function imagePicker() {
    $(".selectIco").on("click", function() {
      $(".iconSelect").html("");
      $(this).clone().appendTo(".iconSelect");
      $(thisIcon).html("");
      $(".iconSelect img").clone().appendTo(thisIcon);
    })
  }
  imagePicker();
})

$(".test1").click(function() {
  code = "test1";
  console.log(code);
})
$(".test2").click(function() {
  code = "test2";
  console.log(code);
})

//code
$('.cloner1').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if ($(this).children("img").length > 0) {
    iconA = $(this).children(".selectIco").attr("value");
    code = "A=" + iconA;

    console.log("export of code = " + code);

  }
});
$('.cloner2').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if ($(this).children("img").length > 0) {
    iconA = $(this).children(".selectIco").attr("value");
    code = "B=" + iconA;

    console.log("export of code = " + code);

  }
});
```

```css
.iconSelect {
  height 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.clone {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.icons {
  display: none;
}

.test1,
.test2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>first</h1>
<div class="test1">clickme</div>
or
<div class="test2">clickme</div>
<br/>

<h1>second</h1>
<div class="clone cloner1">A</div>
<div class="clone cloner2">B</div>

<div class="iconSelect"></div>
<div class="icons">
  <img class="selectIco" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/100px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" value="/1a">
  <img class="selectIco" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Gmail_Icon.svg/100px-Gmail_Icon.svg.png" value="/1b">
</div>
```

Comment: It overwrites whole code. I want to add it up. I need to leave "test1" or "test2" intact inside code and then add up A=/1aB=/1b. So final code would look like this for example: test1A=/1aB=/2a etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how your adding works. Could you clarify please?

Comment: Well it doesnt work, thats why im here :D Concept is easy. In first step, you chose test1 or test2 that adds "test1" or "test2" into code variable as string. In second step i want to leave "test1" or "test2" intact inside code variable and add up to it values of images inside .cloner1 and .cloner2 along with its positions. Cloner1 is position "A" and it has image with value /1a -> test1A=/1a... Cloner2 is position "B" and it has image with value /1b -> test1A=/1aB=/1b.

Comment: So if you select test2, then cloner2, you'll get `test2B=/1b`, but if you select test1, then cloner2, then cloner1, you'll get `test1B=/1bA=/1a`?

Comment: It depends on whats inside cloner2 or cloner1. If you want to have img /1b inside cloner2 then it would be test2B=/1b. If you want to have /1b in cloner2 and /1a in cloner1 then you get test1B=/1bA=/1a. test1 or test2 is there just so i dont delete whole string inside code variable

Comment: 1. step => code = test1 / test2
2. step => code = test / test2 + A=1a / 1b + B=1a / 1b